# i do not understand how to fix code, gives the error of char cannot be converted to boolean and char cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java, char

```
private void strcpyKeepCase(char  into, char  putString, String src, int srcLen) {
    if(numLower +numUpper ==0){
        into =  putString;

    }else if(numLower ==0){
        // all upper :
        while (putString) {
            into = Character.toUpperCase(putString);
            putString = putString.substring(1);
        }
        into = 0;

    }else if(numUpper ==0){
        // all lower :
        while (putString) {
            into = Character.toLowerCase(putString);
            putString = putString.substring(1);
        }
        into = 0;
    }else if(numUpper ==1&&Character.isLetter(src.charAt(0))&&Character.isUpperCase(src.charAt(0))){
        // first upper then low

        if (putString) //&& isalpha(*putString) ){
            into = Character.toUpperCase(putString);
            putString = putString.substring(1);
        }
        while (putString) {
            into = Character.toLowerCase(putString);
            putString = putString.substring(1);
        }
        into = 0;

    }else{
            // just copy putString - it should be mixed
            into = putString;
        }
    }
```

i do not understand the code, as i am new to coding in java. it gives the error of java incompatible types: char cannot be converted to boolean and java: char cannot be dereferenced. i do not understand what it means and how to fix it. any help will be greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: What do you try to achieve with `while (putString)` ?

Comment: You don't need to pass `into` as variable as you don't use it, create it in the method

Comment: to use into as a pointer to putString

Comment: how do i create into in a method?

Comment: Did you mean `while (putString != \u0000)`? Java and C are different in the way they use booleans.

Comment: yes. that worked but i still have an error of "char cannot be dereferenced"

Comment: the error is at putString = putString.substring(1);